# sched_setaffinity fails when called in core_pattern called procedure

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern set to pipe core dumps to my program. This program calls a shell script (using "system") which in turn calls my test program, attached. This test program attempts to call sched_setaffinity which fails, EINVAL, for any CPU. The same test program called directly from a shell script (running as root) works OK.

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <syslog.h>


typedef unsigned long long int UINT64;

// Functions to convert Linux CPU list to/from UINT64
static UINT64 GetCpuMask(cpu_set_t* cpuSet)
{
    UINT64 mask = 0;
    const int maxCpus = CPU_SETSIZE < 64?CPU_SETSIZE:64;
    for (int cpu = 0; cpu < maxCpus; cpu++){
        mask |= CPU_ISSET(cpu, cpuSet)? 1ll<<cpu : 0;
    }
    return mask;
}
static void GetCpuSet(UINT64 mask, cpu_set_t* cpuSet)
{
    const int maxCpus = CPU_SETSIZE < 64?CPU_SETSIZE:64;
    CPU_ZERO(cpuSet);
    for (int cpu = 0; cpu < maxCpus; cpu++){
        if (1ll<<cpu & mask){
            CPU_SET(cpu, cpuSet);
        }
    }
}
UINT64 GetThreadAffinityMask()
{
    cpu_set_t cpuSet;

    if (!sched_getaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuSet)){
        return GetCpuMask(&cpuSet);
    }
    syslog (LOG_ERR, "sched_getaffinity fails, errno %d:%s", errno, strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
// Temp test...
    setlogmask (LOG_UPTO (LOG_INFO)); // unless overridden in config file
    openlog ("proc3", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_USER );

    UINT64 old_mask=GetThreadAffinityMask();
    syslog (LOG_INFO, "old_mask 0x%x", old_mask);

    cpu_set_t testCpuSet;
    for (int cpu = 0; cpu < 16; cpu++){
        CPU_ZERO(&testCpuSet);
        CPU_SET(cpu, &testCpuSet);
        UINT64 try_mask = GetCpuMask(&testCpuSet);
        if (!sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &testCpuSet)){
            syslog (LOG_INFO, "sched_setaffinity OK, cpu %d (mask 0x%x)",cpu, try_mask);
            UINT64 new_mask = GetThreadAffinityMask();
            syslog (LOG_INFO, "new_mask 0x%x", new_mask);
        } else {
            syslog (LOG_INFO, "sched_setaffinity, cpu %d errno %d:%s", cpu, errno, strerror(errno));
        }
    }
}
```

The logged output when called directly from a root shell:

```
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: old_mask 0xf
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity OK, cpu 0 (mask 0x1)
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: new_mask 0x1
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity OK, cpu 1 (mask 0x2)
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: new_mask 0x2
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity OK, cpu 2 (mask 0x4)
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: new_mask 0x4
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity OK, cpu 3 (mask 0x8)
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: new_mask 0x8
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 4 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 5 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 6 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 7 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 8 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 9 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 10 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 11 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 12 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 13 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 14 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:42:43 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[9122]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 15 errno 22:Invalid argument
```

The logged output when called from the dump hook:

```
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: old_mask 0xf
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 0 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 1 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 2 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 3 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 4 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 5 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 6 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 7 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 8 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 9 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 10 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 11 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 12 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 13 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 14 errno 22:Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:50:25 apxdev-cjn-1 proc3[12372]: sched_setaffinity, cpu 15 errno 22:Invalid argument
```

Comment: I only see two possible causes of EINVAL in the source: (1) the `PF_NO_SETAFFINITY` flag is set in the task flags (but that is supposed to be cleared when a user-mode program is exec'd - at least in recent versions), or (2) this condition fails: `cpumask_intersects(new_mask, cpu_valid_mask)` (but I don't see how that would be the case given you're trying every possible `new_mask`). What kernel version are you running?

Comment: 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 16 17:03:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Can I look at the value of PF_NO_SETAFFINITY? That looks like a possibility, given that the process was started by kernel (as result of core_pattern set).

Comment: I'm trying to set affinity from a shell spawned (fork/exec, using system call) from the kernel process that was created for the core_pattern pipe. Is the PF_NO_SETAFFINITY flag inherited by child processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the addition of the kernel version, an answer:

It appears that `EINVAL` in the `sched_setaffinity` call is due to the `PF_NO_SETAFFINITY` flag being set in the task flags. This flag is enabled in most kernel threads to ensure that user-level programs don't manipulate the affinity of the kernel thread in inappropriate ways.

In later versions of the kernel, code was added to the `flush_old_exec` function in `fs/exec.c` causing the flag to be cleared when a user-level helper program is exec'd (such as that invoked by the piped `core_pattern` function here).

The source for the kernel version specified by OP is available at https://buildlogs.centos.org/c7.1511.u/kernel/20160217024115/3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64/. The code that clears `PF_SET_NOAFFINITY` when exec'ing a user-mode program is not present in this version.

This flag will be inherited by child processes (AFAICT: the entire task structure is copied and I cannot see anything that would clear it).

According to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt, the `flags` value should be visible in `/proc/<pid>/stat` (`PF_SET_NOAFFINITY` in this version is #defined to 0x04000000). You should be able to decode the values there and determine for sure whether the flag is set.

Comment: Thanks. But I can’t make much sense of /proc/<pid>/stat!

Here it is in the dump hook:
17690 (cat) R 17672 0 0 0 -1 71311616 275 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 598776060 110501888 154 18446744073709551615 4194304 4238828 140728104308560 140728104308560 140455982119488 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 17 0 0 0 0 0 0 6339656 6341408 29011968 140728104312228 140728104312248 140728104312248 140728104312811 0

Comment: And in my root shell:
21391 (cat) R 8447 21391 8447 34819 21391 4202496 225 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 598781972 110501888 154 18446744073709551615 4194304 4238828 140727254146640 140727254146640 140413179341376 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 17 1 0 0 0 0 0 6339656 6341408 20316160 140727254148856 140727254148876 140727254148876 140727254151147 0

Comment: I'll take your word for it though, and do what I need in another way.

Comment: See table 1-4 in the proc.txt link. It's the ninth field, so in your dump hook, 71311616 == 0x4402100 (has the 0x4000000 bit), but in your root shell it's 4202496 == 0x402000 (doesn't have the bit)

Comment: Yes, that's the smoking gun. Thanks.